# ActionIndicatorView hidden after a some time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to hidden ActionIndicatorView after a 7 seconde for exemple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timer to do this functionalty

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(viewhidefunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

In function make yourview.hidden=TRUE;